# Graph theory dinner party problem

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

In a party of 6 people is it true that there exists four people either all do or all do not knowing each Other?

I know it's false, and have the solution  but not quite sure where to begin with the justification for these types of problem, any tips will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a **counterexample**. Call your people $1$ to $6$, and specify who knows whom and who doesn't. You might do it in words, or with a graph, joining pairs who know each other with a blue line, and people who don't with a red line.

The simplest counterexample is $1$, $2$, $3$ know each other, but nobody else. And $4$, $5$, $6$ know each other, but nobody else. It is obvious that there is no group of $4$ mutual acquaintances, and no group of $4$ mutual strangers.